# el main me da un error y creo que es al añadir el objeto creado al array

Tags: java

El main me da un error y no se porque. Tengo una clase mazo y otra carta de rol y una pequeña interfaz para los metodos. al usar el caso 1 de la interfaz y meter lo datos del objeto carta al final da un error y creo que es al añadir dicho objeto al array mazo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File miFichero = new File("Coleccion.dat");
    Mazo m = null;
    if (!miFichero.exists()) {
        m = new Mazo();
        System.out.println(m.toString());
    } else {
        // m = deserializa();
    }

    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean salir = false;
    int opcion; // Guardaremos la opcion del usuario

    while (!salir) {
        System.out.println("*********************************************");
        System.out.println("1. Añadir una nueva carta");
        System.out.println("2. Buscar carta por su nombre");
        System.out.println("3. Eliminar una carta");
         System.out.println("4. Listar  todas las cartas");
        System.out.println("4. Listar  todas las cartas nuevas");
        System.out.println("5. Listar  todas las cartas segunda mano");
        System.out.println("6. Buscar la carta mas cara");
        System.out.println("7. Buscar la carta mas barata");
        System.out.println("8. Buscar la carta mas antigua");
        System.out.println("9. Salir");
        System.out.println("*********************************************");

        System.out.println("Elija una de las opciones");

        opcion = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());

        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                String aux = "",
                 aux1 = "",
                 aux2 = "";
                int aux3 = 0,
                 aux4 = 0;
                double aux5 = 0;
                CartaDeRol carta1 = new CartaDeRol();
                System.out.println("nombre de la carta: " + aux);
                aux = entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("tipo de carta: " + aux1);
                aux1 = entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Descripcion: " + aux2);
                aux2 = entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Cuantos dueños a tenido antes? " + aux3);
                aux3 = entrada.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Año de creacion: " + aux4);
                aux4 = entrada.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Precio: " + aux5);
                aux5 = entrada.nextDouble();
                carta1.setNombre(aux);
                carta1.setTipo(aux1);
                carta1.setDescripcion(aux2);
                carta1.setNumDueniosAnt(aux3);
                carta1.setAnioCreacion(aux4);
                carta1.setPrecio(aux5);
                m.addCarta(carta1);

                break;

            case 2:
```

Este es el metodo añardir carta.

```
 public String addCarta(CartaDeRol carta1) {
    String resultado = "";
    if (mazo[mazo.length-1] == null) {
        mazo[this.getNumelementos() + 1] = carta1;
        resultado = "Carta anadida";
    } else {
        resultado = "mazo completo";
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Os muestro el erro del main.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>     at tarea7.Mazo.addCarta(Mazo.java:85)   at
>   tarea7.GestionDelMazo.main(GestionDelMazo.java:79)
>   C:\Users\ck\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 33 seconds)

clase mazo

```
public class Mazo implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private CartaDeRol[] mazo;
private int numelementos;

public Mazo(CartaDeRol[] mazo, int numelementos) {
    this.mazo = mazo;
    this.numelementos = numelementos;
}

public Mazo() {
    this.mazo = new CartaDeRol[numelementos];
    this.numelementos = 10;
}

public CartaDeRol[] getMazo() {
    return mazo;
}

public void setMazo(CartaDeRol[] mazo) {
    this.mazo = mazo;
}

public int getNumelementos() {
    return numelementos;
}

public void setNumelementos(int numelementos) {
    this.numelementos = numelementos;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String aux = "Mazo{" + "mazo" + mazo + '}';
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getNumelementos(); i++) {
        aux += mazo[i].toString();
    }
    return aux;
}

public String buscarCartaXNombre(String nombre) {
    String resultado = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getNumelementos(); i++) {
        if (nombre.compareToIgnoreCase(mazo[i].getNombre()) == 0) {
            resultado = mazo[i].toString();
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}

public boolean eliminarCarta(String nombre) {
    boolean borrado = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getNumelementos(); i++) {
        if (nombre.compareToIgnoreCase(mazo[i].getNombre()) == 0) {
            mazo[i] = null;
            borrado = true;
        } else if (borrado == true) {
            mazo[i - 1] = mazo[i];
        }

        if (i == this.getNumelementos() - 1 && borrado == true) {
            mazo[i] = null;
        }
    }
    return borrado;
}

public String addCarta(CartaDeRol carta1) {
    String resultado;
    if (mazo[mazo.length-1] == null) {
        mazo[this.getNumelementos() + 1] = carta1;
        resultado = "Carta anadida";
    } else {
        resultado = "mazo completo";
    }
    return resultado;
}

public String listaCartaN() {
    String aux = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getNumelementos(); i++) {
        if (mazo[i].getNumDueniosAnt() == 0) {
            aux += "/n " + mazo[i].toString();
        }
    }
    return aux;
}

public String listarCartasV() {
    String aux = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getNumelementos(); i++) {

        if (mazo[i].getNumDueniosAnt() > 0) {
            aux += "/n " + mazo[i].toString();
        }
    }
    return aux;
}

public String listarTCartas() {
    String aux = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getNumelementos(); i++) {
        aux += "/n " + mazo[i].toString();
    }
    return aux;
}

public CartaDeRol buscarCartaCara() {
    CartaDeRol carta1 = new CartaDeRol();
    int posicionCartaMasCara = 0;
    double cara = Double.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < this.getNumelementos(); i++) {
        if (mazo[i].getPrecio() > cara) {
            cara = mazo[i].getPrecio();
            posicionCartaMasCara = i;
        }
    }
    return mazo[posicionCartaMasCara];
}

public CartaDeRol BuscarCartaBarata() {
    double barata = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    int posicionCartaMasBarata = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getNumelementos(); i++) {
        if (mazo[i].getPrecio() > barata) {
            barata = mazo[i].getPrecio();
            posicionCartaMasBarata = i;
        }
    }
    return mazo[posicionCartaMasBarata];
}

public CartaDeRol devCartaAntigua() {
    int antigua = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int posicionCartaMasAntigua = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getNumelementos(); i++) {
        if (mazo[i].getAnioCreacion() < antigua) {
            antigua = mazo[i].getAnioCreacion();
        }
        posicionCartaMasAntigua = i;
    }
    return mazo[posicionCartaMasAntigua];
}
```

}

Comment: Podrias mostrar la clase mazo? apuesto a que el array mazo nunca esta inicializado

Comment: la copio en la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Un pequeño analisis de tu codigo, revela que efectivamente mazo no tiene absolutamente nada.

Veamos las partes relevantes:

```
Mazo m = null;
if (!miFichero.exists()) {
    m = new Mazo();
```

Aca creaste un nuevo mazo (asumiendo que el archivo existe). Usaste el constructor por defecto, que dice lo siguiente:

```
public Mazo() {
    this.mazo = new CartaDeRol[numelementos];
    this.numelementos = 0;
}
```

O sea que la variable mazo es un array con cantidad de elementos numelementos, pero en el constructor no le pasaste el tamaño. 
Y para colmo dijiste despues que vale 0. Tengamos en cuenta, que si no lo inicializaste en la clase, que fue lo que paso, ya valia 0.

Entonces el medoto add va a fallar porque:

```
public String addCarta(CartaDeRol carta1) {
    String resultado = "";
    if (mazo[mazo.length-1] == null) {
        mazo[this.getNumelementos() + 1] = carta1;
        resultado = "Carta anadida";
    } else {
        resultado = "mazo completo";
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

mazo.length = 0, entonces aca puede estar tirando error, porque estas buscando la posición -1 de ese array.
Supongamos que no tira error, es peor, porque:
mazo[this.getNumelementos() + 1] es el elemento 1 de mazo, pero recordemos que mazo esta incializado en 0. 
y tambien va a tirar error. o sea, el primer elemento de mazo, es el 0.

Y mazo, tiene que tener un tamaño considerable, porque si tu array se queda sin espacio nunca lo estas controlando.

### Nota importante

Modificar la variable numelementos despues de usarla para crear al array, no hace que cambie el tamaño del array. El array se crea con el tamaño que se le da en el momento de crearlo. Entonces es importante que de antemano sepas el tamaño del mismo. Y controles en todos lados no pasarte del tamaño asignado.

Comment: he probado a darle el valor 10 en el constructor pero no me da error. este
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at tarea7.Mazo.toString(Mazo.java:50)
 at tarea7.GestionDelMazo.main(GestionDelMazo.java:33)
C:\Users\ck\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Ahora te da error en otro lado. Ahora habria que revisar que le pasa a ese metodo. @carlosdiaz fijate de ir depurando tu codigo paso a paso a ver que pasa

Comment: @carlosdiaz ese metodo va hasta numelementos. Estas seguro que tiene el valor correcto?

Comment: he eliminado el printi de debajo de si no hay archivo y ya si funciona pero da el error 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at tarea7.Mazo.addCarta(Mazo.java:84)
 at tarea7.GestionDelMazo.main(GestionDelMazo.java:84)
C:\Users\ck\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 43 seconds)
te modifico la clase mazo para que la veas en la pregunta

Comment: No. No modifiques la pregunta, porque entonces la respuesta queda invalida y asi no funciona el sitio. Vas a tener que ir paso a paso, verificando porque falla cada cosa. @carlosdiaz

Comment: dejame edito la respuesta. @carlosdiaz

Comment: Soy muy nuevo en programacion y no se depurar paso a paso y ver donde falla

Comment: @carlosdiaz bueno carlos, lo primero que tenes que hacer es aprender a depurar paso a paso. segun la ide que uses, en google hay montones de tutoriales que te enseñan a hacerlo. y si lo haces, vas a ir encontrando todos los errores que tenes uno a uno. Asi como esta, la clase no parece servir.

Answer (score 0):

El fallo estaba en el constructor. tenia que tener el array max elemetos y num elementos y entonces el array lo creo en el constructor sin paramentros con MAXELEMENTOS como constante. y me faltaba un numelementos++ en el metodo addcarta